# Sqlite3 : return index of a row and find a row via index

Tags: c++, sqlite

I want to do something like this:

```
db.Query("SELECT `username` FROM `accounts` WHERE `index` = '$'", "1")
```

and this:

```
db.Query("SELECT `index` FROM `accounts` WHERE `username` = '$'", "something")
```

Comment: What do yuo mean with "index"? In SQL, an index [is something different](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html). Do you know what a primary key is? Does your `accounts` table have an `ID` column?

Comment: by index i mean their order number like the first row index is 1 , the second row index is 2, i don't have an id column.

i didn't mean this index http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html

Comment: In SQL, rows in a table are not ordered. What you want is probably the [`rowid`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid). And you really should learn about basic database design and primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

There really is no "index" as you describe it in Sqlite.  Hopefully your database has some row that has unique id's in it. If you want to understand how your particular database is put together, load it up [like sqlite database browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/) and you will be able to see what your tables and rows look like.  Then you can make more sensible queries.

Your query will then look more like:

```
 db.Query("SELECT username FROM accounts WHERE dumrowid = ?", "1");
```

where dumrowid is whatever your database browser says the name of your row is that has the id you are looking for.